# MPAndroidChart How to add the last dashed line with no entry

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm redesigning MPAndroidChart to my project. I want to add start and end empty entries (like in the photo). Is it possible to do it at all?
[image]

Comment: @whiterabbitj it is screenshot in figma

Comment: Do you mean horizontal lines before 91.0 and after 89.0?

Comment: @Gagan yes :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct API in `LineChartRenderer` to give you that behaviour. You might have to extend `LineChartRenderer` class *(and then override `drawDataSet()` method)* to provide this custom behaviour for the first and the last entries within `LineDataSet`. That's what I did for a similar requirement.